# android java change language programatically

Tags: java, android, locale

I have an application which has a activity which handles switching fragments

```
public void replaceFragment(@IdRes int containerViewId,
                                @NonNull Fragment fragment,
                                @NonNull String fragmentTag
    ) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(containerViewId, fragment, fragmentTag)
                .commitNow();
    }
```

There is a language toggle in the main activity.

I have two strings files strings.xml in my folders values and values-fr

for english and french

Now when i toggle i do this

```
Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Resources resources = activity.getResources();
Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
config.setLocale(locale);
resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
activity.recreate()
```

The activity changes language and the first fragment but none of the others

Please can anyone help. My targetSdkVersion is 31

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes this is the Android configuration setting annoyance.
For some reason changing configurations like these requires you to do this on every single Activity. Want to change to dark mode according to your own app's settings? Have to perform the action on every Activity.

A classic way to circumvent this is to make a base class doing all the grabbing preferences and setting preferences sutff and extending all other classes from that one class.

Sometimes it might not suit your needs to do this, but as far as I had checked last time, every activity has to have prefs set on *usually* the onResume overloaded method.